# How does the amalgamated product not depend on the homomorphisms $\alpha$ and $\beta$?

Tags: group-theory, algebraic-topology

I came across this definition of the amalgamated product in my Algebraic Topology class:

[image: Amalgamated Product]

I was curious as to why the choice of the homomorphisms $\alpha$ and $\beta$ is unimportant to the outcome of the group. Wouldn't the images $i_{G}(\alpha(K))$ and $i_H(\beta(K))$ change depending on these homomorphisms, resulting in different relations for the generators of $G*_KH$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It does depend on $\alpha$ and $\beta$.  It's just customary to leave them out of the notation $G*_KH$, since otherwise it would become a bit unwieldy.

Comment: So then, when we say that a group $G$ is isomorphic to an amalgamated product $A*_CB$, we are just saying that there exist $\alpha:C\rightarrow A$ and $\beta:C\rightarrow B$ that give a group (using the method in the definition) isomorphic to $G$?

Comment: Yes.  Or, more often, we're not just saying such $\alpha$ and $\beta$ exist but we are specifying (sometimes implicitly from context) what they are.

Comment: But how, when all we can see from notation are three groups, can we infer the homomorphisms $\alpha$ and $\beta$?

Comment: You can't. Either they can be inferred from context, or are explicitly given earlier.

Comment: The notation alone does not allow you to infer $\alpha$ and $\beta$.  My point is that a statement like "$G$ is isomorphic to an amalgamated product $A*_CB$" in isolation is actually very rare.  Much more often, such a statement will be accompanied by context that (explicitly or implicitly) tells you what $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are.

Comment: Okay, thank you very much, I think I understand now! One last question pertaining to these products is one of uniqueness - for which $\alpha$ and $\beta$ do we arrive at isomorphic amalgamated products? I tried thinking about it in terms of the universal property, but in these cases we create a diagram that depends on $\alpha$ and $\beta$. Would it simply require that the images are isomorphic?

Comment: No, it does not suffice for the images to be isomorphic.  It is sufficient for there to exist isomorphisms $f:A\to A$, $g:B\to B$, and $h:C\to C$ such that $f\alpha=\alpha' h$ and $g\beta=\beta' h$ (since then you can just apply these isomorphisms to the whole construction).